# Casting improvement for microcontroller

Tags: c, optimization, avr, bit-shift

Is there a way to improve this line of code? I think this conversion slows down my program. I think something like bit shifting can be used, by I am not sure.

`(uint16_t)(0.8*(float)(Value)` ?

EDIT: I need to program the atmega8 microcontroller. My teacher said that this line of code would require more processing power and that there is a simpler way of doing this with bit shifting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm assuming that `Value` is an `int` as well.)

0.8 times `x` is the same as (4 times `x`) divided by five.  Multiplying an integer by a power of 2 can be done very quickly with a bit-shift.  You can do this explicitly if you know how, but any modern compiler will automatically optimize `int x = ...; x *= 8;` to a bit-shift for you, so you don't need to worry about it.  Details about how to do this by hand are widely available if you are interested.

So one thing to try is `(Value * 4) / 5`.

Comment: + Or even better, let it do the rounding for you: `(Value * 8 + 5) / 10`

Comment: True that this will give you a better-rounded answer numerically, at the cost of an extra integer addition (which is a small cost but if this line of code is really "slowing down his program"...), and if Value is 16 bits then multiplying by 8 increases the chance of overflow.